# Securely exporting everything from Outlook to .pst

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to backup all the contents that I currently have in my Outlook e-mail account. Part of the contents (e-mails) have already been archived to another .pst file.

- What exactly would I have to do in order to get all the contents that ever existed in connection to that particular account on one .pst file?
- Furthermore, if I have everything on a .pst file can I secure it to open it with only the account I used to create the .pst file or alternatively can the .pst file be opened by any Outlook account, without issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Transferring PST File Data

For the email data in one PST file to be moved over to another PST file, you can simply attach both PST files one-by-one to the same Outlook profile, and then use the drag and drop or right click, move options from Outlook. See the below details on the procedures for exporting to PST and attaching PST files to Outlook profiles.

### Securing PST File Data

To secure a PST file you can set the password on it as specified below and those that want to attach to it will need to know the password to do so. Refer to [Set a password to help protect your Outlook information](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-a-password-to-help-protect-your-Outlook-information-f60fb0e7-f0ad-4d7c-858b-9619d1b9f0b6) for more detail on this topic.

Furthermore, you should ensure that you only allow those you want to have this data physical access to it. Additionally, using file level encryption (e.g. [PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy), [WinZip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinZip), etc.) for any copies of the PST file where they may reside but not mounted to with Outlook will help ensure the data stays secure. Lastly, using some sort of [full disk encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption) like [BitLocker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker) will ensure the file is encrypted on the machine(s) you do allow the file to reside once created where Outlook will attached to the file.

### Exporting to a PST File

You follow the instructions as per [How to export an Outlook 2010 .pst file](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-export-an-outlook-2010-pst-file-exchange-2010) for the detailed steps of the procedure which I'll quote below.

> ### How to export an Outlook 2010 .pst file
>
> **How to**
>
> 1. Open Outlook 2010.
> 2. Go to **File - Open** and then click on **Import**.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Select **Export** to a file and then click **Next**.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Select **Outlook Data File** (.pst) and then click on Next.
>
>    [image]
> 5. Select the top-most folder, check the box **Include subfolders** and then click on **Next**.
>
>    [image]
> 6. Click on the **Browse** button.
>
>    [image]
> 7. Decide where you will export the .pst file and then click on **OK**.
>
>    [image]
> 8. Click on **Finish**.
> 9. A password box will pop up. Leave all fields blank and just click on
>      **OK**
>
>    [image]
>
> <sub>[source](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-export-an-outlook-2010-pst-file-exchange-2010)</sub>

### Attaching Outlook to a PST File

To open a PST file see the Microsoft [Open and close Outlook Data Files (.pst)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-and-close-Outlook-Data-Files-pst-381b776d-7511-45a0-953a-0935c79d24f2#ID0EAACAAA=2010) and choose the 2010 option if needed for the detailed steps which I'll quote below

> ### Open and close Outlook Data Files (.pst)
>
> Open an Outlook Data File (.pst)
>
> If you have an Outlook Data File (.pst) that doesn't appear in the
>   Navigation Pane, you can add it so that you can work with the items in
>   the data file.
>
> 1. On the **File** tab, click **Account Settings** > **Account Settings**.
>
>    [image]
> 2. On the **Data Files** tab, click **Add**.
> 3. Click the Outlook Data File (.pst) file that you want to open, and then click **OK**.
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-and-close-Outlook-Data-Files-pst-381b776d-7511-45a0-953a-0935c79d24f2#ID0EAACAAA=2010)</sub>